# How can I delete a folder with 65535 links?

Tags: macos, hardlink

Somehow a folder from `/var/folders` (`/var/folders/2j/8_50ggln3wz21k4gmfx86drh0000gn/T/` on my machine) got 65535 links to it. 
This caused my machine to not boot anymore.
I managed to fix the booting issue my renaming it to something else (`mv T X`) in recovery mode.

The problem is I can't get rid of it (`rm -rf` or even `ls` on it hangs).

```
ls -tahl ~/.Trash
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+    67 <user>  staff   2.1K Nov 30 00:30 ..
drwxr-x---  65535 <user>  staff   139M Nov 29 22:14 X
drwx------      3 <user>  staff    96B Nov 29 22:01 .
```

And if I try:

```
rm -r ~/.Trash/X
...(hanged, does not return)
```

Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: How long did you wait?  Maybe its just taking a long time, did you try waiting an hour?

Comment: Hi, I've waited for more than 1h. Also empty trash gives up after ~10 minutes and does not do anything. The folder has only ~130MB

Comment: While in recovery mode, did you run Disk Utility's First Aid feature? 2^16 links sounds like filesystem corruption to me.

Comment: Please don't crosspost to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307392/how-to-delete-a-folder-that-has-65535-links-on-it

Comment: @Spiff yes, the check was OK. I'm worried about that number because of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5629/is-there-a-limit-of-hardlinks-for-one-file . I will just wait longer for now..

Comment: Managed to remove the folder. I've used verbose mode and saw the progress